# How set epoch on ESP32 and Arduino IDE to update the timedate without external RTC and Wifi?

Tags: time, arduino, epoch, esp32

On my ESP32 I want to have information about actual time without Wifi connection or an external RTC chip. I started with this simple code

```
time_t now;
struct tm* timeinfo;

void Check_Time(void) {
  time(&now);
  timeinfo = localtime(&now);
  Serial.println(timeinfo);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Check_Time();
  delay(1000);
}
```

It works since the output is

```
Thu Jan  1 00:07:57 1970
Thu Jan  1 00:07:58 1970
Thu Jan  1 00:07:59 1970
Thu Jan  1 00:08:00 1970
...
```

and naturally it starts from 1 Jan 1970. Now I want to update this time to the actual one but I haven't found a direct solution. I know that I could convert a date to a `time_t` data with the `mktime` function (is it right?) but how I can pass it to the system? How I should manage this problem?

Comment: I don't really know what you want to be honest? you said "without WiFi" and "without RTC chip", yet you "want to update this time", so what do you mean you want to update? manually?

Comment: @hcheung Yes, I want to update it manually inside my application. "without Wifi" means without the use of some sort of sntp server (without internet) and "without RTC chip" means using the RTC integrated in the ESP32. If through the `time(&now)` command I get the epoch of the system, is there a function to set this value?

Comment: tm is a struct that you can set the value to it, is [this](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/) what you are looking for?

Comment: @hcheung with the mktime I obtain a `time_t` data. If I execute `time(&now)` after `mktime` I get (for example) `Thu Jan  1 00:08:00 1970` again: I don't update the system time with `mktime` function.

Comment: I guess you never look at the example on the link that I provided.

Comment: @hcheung Yes, I saw the example you provided and it is not what I'm looking for. You didn't understand and maybe I was unclear. When I start my application on the ESP32 module the system time is set at the begin of the epoch (Jan 1 00:00:00 1970) and that is what I obtain when I execute the function `time(&now)` in my code above, ok. But now I want to modify (if possible!!!) the system time so when I execute the `time(&now)` function again I obtain the modified date.

Comment: The problem is that you keep assumed that what you are looking for existed in `time.h` or `ctime.h` library, the thing is that it simply doesn't exist. You will have to use the tm struct to set the new time, and generate the time_since_epoch using mktime(), then you will have to create your function to get the time(&now) which is a timer value, add it to the new tm struct that you create and do all the math and maintenance as the timer changed. I don't know what is your usage scenario is, but since you insist of no wifi and no RTC hardware, this is the only way (and the hard way) to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by using:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
// ...
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = /* seconds since epoch here */;
tv.tv_usec = /* microseconds here */;
settimeofday(&tv, NULL);
```

Replacing the comments with the variable that stores the times.

I am updating my time over Bluetooth Low Energy.

Here is it working:

```
1970 1 1 0 0 16
1970 1 1 0 0 17
1970 1 1 0 0 18
Time set
2020 12 6 22 45 32
2020 12 6 22 45 33
2020 12 6 22 45 34
```